# Visual Studio 2017 middle dot hotkey

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've noticed a shourtcut `Ctrl+·, Ctrl+·` for `File.CloseAllButThis` operation in VS 2017.
How do I call this shortcut?
Is there a button for this middle dot on a keabord?

In VS 2015 it was empty.
I also have Resharper 2017.1 EAP 4 installed on my Win10 PC, probably it is somehow related to question.

[image]